# Loop through JSON and add value to var

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I have this code in JavaScript to generate an encrypted value:

```
const sodium = require('tweetsodium');
var key = "";
var value = "";

// Convert the message and key to Uint8Array's (Buffer implements that interface)
const messageBytes = Buffer.from(value);
const keyBytes = Buffer.from(key, 'base64');


// Encrypt using LibSodium.
const encryptedBytes = sodium.seal(messageBytes, keyBytes);


// Base64 the encrypted secret
const encrypted = Buffer.from(encryptedBytes).toString('base64');


//console.log(value) + console.log(encrypted);
console.log(encrypted);
```

I have multiple this json file:

```
[
{
   "key": "12345",
   "value": "test"

},
{
   "key": "54321",
   "value": "test2"
}
];
```

How can I call this external json file from my javascript file and for each "key" and "value" from the json file, add the value to the const key and const value and generate the encrypted value (forEach?)?
Like if I have 4 sets of key and value in the JSON file, it will generate 4 encrypted values.

Comment: Put the code that generates the encrypted value in a function. Then call that function in a `forEach` loop that updates each object.

Comment: `const key = ""` and `const value=""` are immutable and will always be an empty string